# How can i make this condition dynamic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

fieldName is a variable and is dynamic and the value can be either media, media2 or media3.

How can i make "media" be either media, media1 or media3.

instead of doing this...

```
if(fieldName === 'media') {
const newObj = { ...objComponent, media: json.media };
} if(fieldName === 'media2') {
const newObj = { ...objComponent, media2: json.media };
} else {
const newObj = { ...objComponent, media3: json.media };
}
```

Comment: This needs more information to be answerable. Where is `objComponent` coming from? Why are you doing this?

Comment: Why do you need different keys for the same value? Usually that ends up messy and harder to access later on. I would rather do something like `{ ...objComponent, media: json.media, type: fieldName}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass key with brackets `[]` like below

```
const newObj = { ...objComponent, [fieldName]: json.media };
```

That would help you pass dynamic string keys to your object.

Comment: if i were to do now {objComponent.media && objComponent.media.url ? how can i have the media dynamic with fieldName also? thanks

Comment: can i do  {objComponent.[fieldName] && objComponent.[fieldName].url ? ?

Comment: You can do like this `objComponent[fieldName] && objComponent[fieldName].url`. You should keep in mind that you don't need to have `.` between your object and `fieldName` access. If you're using ES6, you can implement it this way as well `objComponent[fieldName]?.url` @BrianMillot

Answer (score 2):

You can use object's `dynamic keys`, where variable name can be used as key inside the object. The syntax is surrounding the key with `[]` and the variable as the key.

```
// fieldName = media or media2 or media3
const newObj = { ...objComponent, [fieldName]: json.media};
```

Comment: Thabks! is it possible to then do something like can i do {objComponent.[fieldName] && objComponent.[fieldName].url ? ?

Comment: yes, you can use [optional chaining opertaor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) like this. `objComponent[fieldName]?.url` It returns `undefined` if `objComponent[fieldName]` is not present and react wont render `undefined` in the UI.